# Spotify not launching

Tags: spotify

I have updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and installed spotify from snap, but it does not launch. I've tried several solutions, but none is working. Can anyone help me, please?

This is what I get when I try to run spotify

```
$ spotify
2018/09/16 14:06:45.629930 cmd_run.go:708: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/home/yaizaragones/snap/spotify/21": mkdir /home/yaizaragones/snap/spotify: permission denied
cannot create user data directory: /home/yaizaragones/snap/spotify/21: Permission denied
```

If I do it with sudo...

```
$ sudo spotify
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/spotify/21/snap/spotify/21/Documents': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/spotify/21/snap/spotify/21/Escriptori': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/spotify/21/snap/spotify/21/Baixades': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/spotify/21/snap/spotify/21/Música': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/spotify/21/snap/spotify/21/Imatges': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/spotify/21/snap/spotify/21/Vídeos': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/spotify/21/snap/spotify/21/Plantilles': No such file or directory
No protocol specified

(spotify:29226): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: does the regular .deb work? Try following the instructions for the .deb here: https://www.spotify.com/it/download/linux/